# how to return multiple rows from a table where each row have one common value out of multiple values which is separated by comma in a single column

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `business_details` and `business_services`

`business_details` table have multiple column, but for this query I am using two columns `Business_Details_Id`(foreign key for business_services) and `Business_Details_Type`. From `business_services` I am using a single column `Business_Services_Names` which has multiple values that are separated by a comma.

I want to return all `Business_Details_Id` after taking input from user which is either a `Business_Details_Type` or a `Business_Services_Names` (out of multiple values).

I can't use `LIKE` to avoid unwanted URLs.FIND_IN_SET returning only one row.

Here is the query i tried:

```
SELECT business_details.Business_Details_Id
FROM business_details
    LEFT JOIN business_services ON 
        business_details.Business_Details_Id = business_services.Business_Details_Id
WHERE business_details.Business_Details_Active = 1
    AND business_details.Business_Details_Type = '$category'
    OR FIND_IN_SET('$category', business_services.Business_Services_Names);
```

`Business_Details_Active` is for displaying only those results having value 1

Comment: include db schema, sample data and desire output. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

First things, if you only want `business_Details.business_details_Active` results of `1` then you need to separate that from your `OR` condition:

```
SELECT business_details.Business_Details_Id
FROM business_details
    LEFT JOIN business_services ON 
        business_details.Business_Details_Id = business_services.Business_Details_Id
WHERE business_details.Business_Details_Active = 1
    AND 
         (
            business_details.Business_Details_Type = '$category'
            OR FIND_IN_SET('$category', business_services.Business_Services_Names)
         );
```

Second, you really don't need the `OR`. You could just concatenate your two fields and do your `Find_In_Set` against the result:

```
SELECT business_details.Business_Details_Id
FROM business_details
    LEFT JOIN business_services ON 
        business_details.Business_Details_Id = business_services.Business_Details_Id
WHERE business_details.Business_Details_Active = 1
    AND FIND_IN_SET('$category', CONCAT_WS(business_services.Business_Services_Names, business_details.Business_Details_Type));
```

Using `Concat_WS()` will bring in that `business_details_type` into your comma delimited `business_services_name` field with a comma of it's own, which should allow `FIND_IN_SET()` to work it's magic.

**Two other things:**

From they [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set): `Find_In_Set()` "... does not work properly if the first argument contains a comma (“,”) character." Just to keep in mind if this still isn't working for you.

Also, Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection since you are taking in User input and dropping it straight into your code. I'm not certain what scripting language you are working in to capture that variable and pass it to your SQL, but it would be a very wise decision to at least sanitize before adding it to the SQL.

Comment: I tried using above query still it only works for Business_Details_Type. It is not displaying results as per Business_Services_Names

Comment: Are your values in `business_services_name` comma delimited, or is there some other character used as the delimiter? Can you share an example of one of those records?

Comment: Yes it is.services are like "Fitness Center, Silm Fit, Health Product Dealer, Healthy Food Product,Wellness Center"